# Why is a song's radio edit called a ‘7" version’?

Tags: vocabulary, music

For some reason, I used to think that a *7" version* of a song was a 7-minute long version.

Then, I started noticing that most 7" versions I came across were in fact around 3:30 long. Upon further inspection (understand *"I googled the question"*), I found that *7" version* was another expression for the [radio edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_edit) of a song.

My best guess would be that, back in the day, the vinyls used for radio edits were 7 inches in diameter (or radius?) but I can't find this information anywhere.

Surely, someone knows more about this?

---

**EDIT (for context)**: I'm seeing this *7" version* thing a lot in song titles.

For instance, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCQYdgYG7uY) is *Rasputin (7" version)*, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SHOVCF8Pq4) is *Tied Up - 7" version*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was `7" version`, that is, 7 inch version.  The reference was to the diameter. They were 45RPM.  Very few pop radio stations would play any song that was seven minutes long.

Comment: The question title's punctuation could do with clarification -- at the moment there are mismatched quotes, and the OP could also clarify whether they're guessing at the punctuation of what they heard, or guessing at the meaning of what they read.

Comment: @TRomano In the UK those vinyls were called "forty-fives". I have forgotten the RPM of the standard vinyls (8 or 9 inch, I believe). LPs were "long-players" or "twelve-inchers".

Comment: This question makes me feel so very old.

Comment: @WS2 Pretty sure they're called "45's" everywhere else too.  At least everywhere that speaks English anyhow.

Comment: @RosieF I'm pretty sure my quotes match one another. I surrounded the _7" version_ with single typographic quotes, because using double quotes would have clashed with the straight double quote from _7" version_.

Comment: @WS2, LPs are usually 33rpm.

Comment: @RosieF there are single quotes in the right spot. The double quote stands for inches and is also in the right spot. Maybe it was edited since your comment, but there are no mismatched quotes there now.

Comment: If you want to be fancy with the Unicode, it's not a *7" version* or a *7” version* but a *7″ version*. The symbol is a double-prime symbol rather than a double quotation mark, so it's slanted (unlike the typewriter-style double quote) and not curled (unlike the publication-style double quote).

Comment: Note that `7"` would spoken as "seven inch".

Comment: @RogerLipscombe But what was the speed and diameter of the standard vinyl? I think they were 78 rpm. But were they 8 or 9 inch?

Comment: @WS2 If you insist that "standard vinyl" means 78rpm then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph_record#78_rpm_disc_sizes - though note that you are talking about pre-1948

Comment: Roger Lipscombe - "LPs are usually 33rpm" if my turntable played LPs at that speed, I'd get it fixed.

Comment: @Henry [This is what I am talking about](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/520987714/collectible-music-record-old-rare-vinyl?gpla=1&gao=1&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_uk_en_gb_christmas-books_movies_and_music&utm_custom1=43adc858-edfb-4399-b01e-b9c2d45ba66f&utm_content=go_1469261683_58093103278_283030015359_pla-314262775427_c__520987714engb&gclid=CjwKCAiA45njBRBwEiwASnZT516NnyvJFKr-wMQwDjG0_tV7JnUzWbCtuUfL_I4vV750LQWTjtIXjxoC1_IQAvD_BwE). We had these in the 1950s and early 60s.

Comment: @TannerSwett Except you italicized the double quote, so now it *is* slanted.

Comment: @TRomano "Stairway to Heaven" gets significant airplay.

Comment: @Accumulation: Not on "pop" stations.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, likewise :( It's quite depressing.

Comment: @WS2 78s were normally 10", I think.

Comment: It doesn't pertain to the songs that have been discussed, but 10" was the diameter of standard 78 rpm records.

Comment: **LOL** older people will find this question funny !  I guess in the far future someone will ask something like **"What is this 'web' thing I see mentioned, and does it relate to the strange 'www' abbreviation?"**   Heh !

Comment: @RussellBorogove Kind of like my answer here? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60920/meaning-of-55-jumbo/60935#60935

Comment: Reminds me of the t-shirt featuring a cassette tape and a pencil with the text "Future generations will not understand their unique relationship".

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When I was growing up in the '60s, in Australia, there were three common formats of vinyl record available. My comments below are based on my own experience and purchases of records from major bands like The Beatles and The Rolling Stones.

1. Singles:

   - These were the primary format that was used to promote a new song from an artist. The tracks were commonly selected from a newly released, or about to be released, LP (A.K.A. Album).
   - The 'A' side had the song that was being promoted, and played on the radio. The 'B' side was not necessarily of less quality but was not promoted or played as often.
   - They were 7 inch diameter with one song per side.
   - They were played at 45 RPM.
   - Each song was usually about 3 minutes long, give or take 30 seconds. This seemed to be the preferred length for commercial radio stations.
   - This ties in with the the idea that the 7" version is the edit aimed at radio performance.
2. EPs (Extended Play)

   - These were also 7 inch, 45 RPM discs, but with two tracks per side.
   - Again they were usually a selection of tracks from an LP.
   - I think they were, primarily, a way for the record companies to get a higher value than singles for customers (young teens) who could not afford to buy LPs.
3. LPs (Long Play)

   - These were the major works of many artists.
   - They were 12 inch diameter and played at 33 1/3 RPM
   - Playing time was usually around 20 minutes per side.

Comment: That's an outstandingly good, detailed answer from "a new contributor". Kudos. (And the question made you feel as old as it made me feel, right? )

Comment: There were also 78 RPM records that were about the same size as 45's if I recall correctly.  The last time I remember seeing a 78 was when my mom threw out dozens of them that had been glued together by some insect invasion when we lived in Guam in the '60's.  The records couldn't be separated from each other, it looked like the insects had eaten the paper between them and their excretions turned them into a solid cylinder of vinyl.

Comment: @delliotg 78 rpm records were usually made of shellac, although some were made of vinyl. They are still around now because people collect them.

Comment: @jostle One thing missing is that the use of 7" version to mean a radio edit probably rose in popularity due to the rise of 12" singles, which would contain a(t least one) longer remix of a song. This fits the examples given in the question, which come from the disco era, when this practice began. About 20 years or so, teachers and parents would always make some silly remark whenever a vinyl record appeared, saying that we kids wouldn't know what they were, when in fact we all knew what they were because 12" singles were the medium used to play music in night clubs.

Comment: EPs were also used for songs that were too long for standard 7" singles. Hey Jude from The Beatles is an example.

Comment: The original reason for early 7" singles, including Rock'n'Roll numbers, being around 3 minutes long was that a lot of people had existing _gramophones_ that could only play 78rpm records so the early vinyl singles were released in both 7" 45rpm and 10" 78rpm versions. For a variety of reasons only one master was cut so the song was arranged to fit on the 78. They stopped using shellac releasing both formats on vinyl but the wider grooves of the 78 meant that the vinyl 78s were still restricted to around 3 3/12 minutes in length.

Comment: @BoldBen - how can you make one cut that can be spun at both 45 & 78 depending on the size of the platter. That simply makes no sense whatsoever. 45s were also 'microgroove' & simply incompatible with an older 78-only system. Mid-period, transitional systems had a reversible needle that could handle both groove specifications as well as both [or more] speeds.

Comment: I remember 78s as being 10".

Comment: @Tetsujin Not a pressing die but 'cut' in the sense of the original recording, whatever medium that recording was made on. I'm not sure what medium they were using commercially in the late 40s so I used 'cut' rather than 'recording'. The point is that the  production pressing dies for both the 78 and 45 discs were made  from the result of the same studio session in a parallel way to that in which CD and MP3 tracks can be produced from the same original.;

Comment: I think I detect a misunderstanding. An EP ("Extended Play") vinyl record was a seven inch diameter record, just like a standard seven inch Single, but it ran longer (hence the name, _extended_ play): in fact, it ran at only 33 rpm instead of 45 rpm, and the slower speed gave a longer duration. An EP thus took the diameter of a normal 45 rpm record, but was played at the 33 rpm speed of a twelve inch LP ("Long Player"). At 45 rpm, a 7 inch Single lasted about 3 minutes. At 33 rpm, a 12 inch LP lasted about 25 minutes.

Comment: Great answer but I don't remember EPs ever being 7" 45rpm discs, there just wasn't room. Best estimate I can find for maximum length at reasonable quality is 4:30... there have been longer releases of course.

Answer (score 38):

A "7 inch single" was a 7 inch diameter vinyl record, which ran at 45 rpm, with a single song on each side; the main 'A' side the 'B' side which normally had a less popular song.

Comment: Just to support this answer, a typical song on this size of record would be roughly three and a half minutes.  You can fit up to 4:30, but the sound quality suffers when you tightly pack the grooves in the record ([more info](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/mastering-forum/673106-maximum-duration-7-inch-vinyl-optimum-sound.html)

Comment: Songs also came in 12" versions.  It might be also worth pointing out that " is not the symbol for _minute_.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense, since in French (my native language), these records are known as _"45 tours"_ (literally _45 rounds_). There are also _"33 tours"_ vinyls. Could they be the _12" versions_?

Comment: @JdeBP I noticed that too, but I suppose I couldn't have thought of a 7-second long version of a song. :)

Comment: @RichouHunter, yes, 33 rpm records (also called "LPs" or "albums") were typically 12 inches in diameter. There were also 33 rpm 7" records, but the main use for these (AFAIK) was for spoken-word recordings for children.

Comment: @RichouHunter, a 12" single (often called "EP", meaning "extended player") is the same physical size as a 12" album ("LP", meaning "long player"), but is played at 45rpm.  So it's around 10 to 15 minutes long.

Comment: *Less popular* B-Sides: Beach Boys "God Only Knows", Queen "We Will Rock You", Beatles "Hello Goodbye"...

Comment: @Aethenosity - "We Will Rock You", I'll give you; but suggesting "God Only Knows" is once of the *worst* Beach Boys songs is heathenry of the foulest order! :-)

Comment: @Snow [Someone Saved My Life Tonight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Someone_Saved_My_Life_Tonight) ran 6:45

Comment: @Aethenosity - Well, that's different!  It's fine to hate them all *equally*, if you can be *truly* unbiased!!

Comment: I'd just like to mention that 7" singles are also referred to as "45's", as in the popular one off hit "Brimful of Asher". In the early days of records, just after cylinder recordings, records were 78rpm and played for about 3 and a half minutes. Later advancements in phonograph design allowed for the creation of transcription discs and lps, 16 inch and 12 inch respectively. These played at 33 1/3 rpms, and allowed for more than the 11 minutes of continuous sound required for movie soundtracks, and radio broadcasts.

Comment: @TobySpeight No. An EP was 7" played at 33rpm. Radio stations did not deal in 12" singles.

Comment: @user207421 Yes.  [EPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_play) have come in 7, 10 and 12" and been played at 331/3, 45 and 78rpm.  "Saturday night party mix" and late night chill session programs happily play 12" singles.  Also, what's with "[was](https://www.jbhifi.com.au/music/Whats-Hot/Music-on-Vinyl/)" and "[did](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+fm+radio+station+logos+US&tbm=isch)"?

Comment: @RichouHunter Piggybacking off of Dover's comment, these are often referred to simply as "45s". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(music) for more info as well

Comment: @mcalex Most radio stations don't use records anymore; they're digital. Hence the past tense.

Answer (score 27):

I think the point being missed in the otherwise good answers so far comes from a later distinction.

Yes, the 'seven inch' was the format of a 'pop single', *potentially* though not necessarily shortened from a longer album track - but until the 80's no-one would have called that single a 'seven inch', they would have just called it 'a single', as opposed to 'an EP' [Extended Play] 'an album' or earlier 'an LP' [Long Player].

The 7" distinction comes from when people first started making 12" singles - longer cuts intended for the dance floor. Often they would drop for minutes into deconstructed sections not really suitable for home listening & certainly not for mainstream radio. A 12" single would still be played at 45rpm unlike an album; the reasoning being that using all the available space for a 10 minute track as opposed to the 22 minutes of an album at 33rpm, you could space the grooves wider & therefore cut more bass into it.

So the distinction initially came about to differentiate the two physical formats & incidentally their intended audiences.

Later distinctions have come about as more & more different 'mix' versions of tracks became popular, hence the rise of the term 'radio edit' - as for the past few years vinyl formats haven't been so popular, so a lot of those simple 'distinctions by physical size' have been blurred.

Comment: Nice answer but I'm unaware of a 10" version of New Order's Blue Monday, in fact reputedly it was the best-selling 12" of all time. I can't see a 10" version listed on Discogs.com. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @mattfreake - I thought I was, in fact I thought I had it; but my vinyl collection is seriously depleted these days. I could be mistaken, but I'm trying to think what I've got it confused with. Of course trying to Google 10" gets nowhere, it ignores punctuation... I have a friend with a prodigious memory for this type of thing. I've poked to see if he might know.

Comment: @mattfreake - It does seem I'm mis-remembering. My friend agrees that it was 12" only, not 10". I think I must have had a mental wire crossed somewhere. I'll pull that paragraph from the answer. I think it survives without it. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Possibly relevant: the Aerosmith song "Big Ten Inch Record." @mattfreake

Comment: It's the wrong era; 'too early' in effect. 10" had been around a long time, it just became a bit of a 'thing' in the 80s. OMD's Electricity was apparently a 10", & Dire Straits' Walk of life - but i think I was simply mis-remembering Blue Monday as a 10 rather than a 12.

Comment: An excellent explanation.

Answer (score 6):

More typographically precise would be to write 7″ (using a double prime mark) instead of 7" (using a generic double quotation mark).

The OP's initial speculation about 7″ possibly meaning seven minutes seems to be rooted in a misunderstanding of one of the meanings of the double-prime mark. It does not refer to minutes, but rather to seconds:

- 7″ means seven inches or seven seconds.
- 7′ means seven feet or seven minutes.

(Minutes and seconds written this way can be measures of time *or* fractions of angular degrees.)

As other answers have mentioned, in the context of song titles, *7″ Version* does not refer to time; it is just another way of writing *Seven-Inch Version*, meaning a version which was intended for release on a 7-inch single, a.k.a. "a 45".

As compared to the album version of a song, the 7″ version was often edited, sped up, remastered, or sometimes a completely different mix, especially in the 1980s.

You may find that compilation albums and radio stations nowadays often use album versions instead of the original hit single versions; it seems no one remembers or cares what version was actually the one you would hear on the radio at the time.

Comment: I have a friend who worked for many years as a record librarian for the BBC [he's now a producer there] who would most heartily disagree with your last statement, though it's not far off the mark for some stations.

Comment: an outstanding point !

Answer (score 2):

Historically, music was sold as either **singles** (one track often with another track on the "B-side"), **EP** with 3-6 songs, or **LP** or full album with 8-15 songs.

In vinyl records, LPs and later EPs used a 12” (300mm) diameter disc.  Singles used a [7" (178mm) diameter disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(music)#Physical_single).  *Notably, the 7" format was used on jukeboxes*, and it was also liked by radio stations.

So the 7" version is the **mix of the song intended for radio** broadcast. It may have different fade-in/out, may be shortened for brevity, or had its dynamic range altered to suit radio and its listeners' less quiet environments (office, car, etc.)

The term **7" version** became critical to distinguish from a new use of the **[12” single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-inch_single#Later_developments)** format, for [DJ's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_jockey) at nightclubs. They contain a variety of (often outlandish) long-cut remixes of the song, with differing styles or beats optimized for different [dance music styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_music#1990s) (and not radio).  Often the 12" single was the *only* single release, and the *7" version* is one of the tracks on it.